# Meteor transactional operations

Tags: meteor

I want to update 3 meteor collections in a function but only if all three of the updates are successful. Otherwise I'd like to roll back. Is there a good pattern for doing this yet?

Thanks

Comment: Check out [`collection.update`](http://docs.meteor.com/#update). It has an optional callback. If there are no errors you can go ahead with the subsequent update.

Comment: @Prashant I wouldn't recommend this because in the second subsequent step if node suddenly crashes or loses access to the mongodb server the 3rd entry wouldn't be placed in.

Comment: Can that be handled on crash? So basically either ways using state values is mandatory, ya?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

meteor uses mongodb for its database backend which doesn't explicitly support transactions. But there is still a pattern you could use: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/perform-two-phase-commits/

Basically you just put a state value in each of your transactions and only mark them done when everything is complete

Comment: And since `Collection.insert` has a callback parameter, you can use the callback to finalise the transaction

Comment: Using the callback is necessary to continue to next step on the client end, fibers takes care on the server. The callback wouldn't make it transactional if the transaction state attribute pattern isn't used. If there is an interruption at any stage such as an error, one entry would be in and not the other. And if error checking in the callback is used its still vulnerable to a server crash/power failure event.